# React Axios Post Callback Trouble

Tags: reactjs, axios, nodemailer

I am having major difficulties getting a callback using axios.post, to send a mail using nodeMailer. You see, the email gets sent, but it literally prints no console log at all.

This is my code:

```
 handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { email, fullname, number, subject, message } = this.state;


            await axios.post('/api/form', {
                email,
                fullname,
                number,
                subject,
                message
              })
              .then((info)=> {
                this.setState({email: '', fullName: '', subject: '', message: ''});
                Alert.success('Success.', {
                    position: 'top-right',
                    effect: 'jelly',
                    timeout: 4000
                });
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch((e)=> {
                console.log(error);
              });
    }
```

And this is the other code in the server (index.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use((request, response, next) => {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
  });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
  }

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'host',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: '', // generated ethereal user
            pass: '' // generated ethereal password
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"New message "<>', // sender address
        to: 'me', // list of receivers
        subject: 'New message', // Subject line
        html: 'Content here' // plain text body// html body
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
        // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });

});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3001.')
})
```

What seems to be the problem here? I have tried using 'axios.get' and 'axios.request', and this does at least output an error.

Comment: Do you return any `response` from the transporter? I use `axios` and `nodemailer` in the backend but I don't see any response in your code.. do you handle the Promise response from the transporter elsewhere?

Comment: @Sabbin That's the thing, this is my code, except that I obviously have post data in my axios.post call. Could you please share your code with me?

Comment: because its an async action and you do not wait for the response

Comment: I will share an answer with the code for `node` if it's not ok, I'll remove it

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi How would I approach this the correct way, then? I have tried with async and await as well, but I might have done it wrong. Do you have a link you can point me in the right direction with?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/making-a-post-request-in-react-express-nodemailer/197448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a `Promise` in order to wait for the response from the transporter and send it to the front end and be parsed by `axios`

```
const sendMail = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(info);
    }
  });
})
.....other code.....
const status = await sendMail();
res.json({status})
```

> **LE**

Based on your code this is how the `/api/form` route should look like

```
app.post('/api/form', async (req, res) => {

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'host',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: '', // generated ethereal user
      pass: '' // generated ethereal password
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"New message "<>', // sender address
    to: 'me', // list of receivers
    subject: 'New message', // Subject line
    html: 'Content here' // plain text body// html body
  };

  const sendMail = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error.message);
      } else {
        resolve(`Message sent: ${info.messageId}`);
      }
    });
  });

  const status = await sendMail();
  res.json({ status });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a quick question, do I paste this code client-side in my contact-form or the index.js (server)?

Comment: in the `server`

Comment: This still doesn't work. I can't see any output in the console. Is it because I am running in on the dev server?

Comment: no, it's not... I don't know your entire code in order to give you some specific help... how do you handle your route, does it get to the right controller, does your controller execute the function above... it's quite complex to simply answer without the entire code..

Comment: I have now updated the code with pretty much everything that I use. Is this helping? Please let me know if you need any more information from me.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your code. Now you should get a response in `axios` in the front  end

Comment: You can also remove the `await` in the front end from the `axios`

Comment: wow! That worked! The only problem I'm facing now, is the fact that I get an error when I try to setState afer then(), and it says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. What seems to be the problem here? By the way, thank you so much!

Comment: I cannot see the `setState` method in your React code, can you update the code?

Comment: I solved the problem, I have now updated the code with a fully working code for everyone else to check out if they're stuck with the same problem.